# Optimal control of the gradient type PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, optimal-control

I recently encountered the following optimal control problem.

We have an object described by a *quasi-PDE* of a gradient type with the ability to apply an input control action $u$:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}+u$

where $F=\frac{1}{(x-x_*)^2+1}$, and $x_*$ - constant, at which the maximum function is reached.

The purpose of the control is to find the value of the controlled parameter $x$, at which the maximum of the function $F$.

The task is complicated by the fact that the transition process of the transition from the initial point $x(0)$ to the final one $x=x_*$ has a hard form due to the nonlinearity of the static map $F$).

We have two variants:

1. It is necessary to make sure that the transition process from any initial state $x(0)$ to an extremum point occurs exponentially, i.e.use one of the cost functions $J$ suggested in the answer, then the solution will look like this, where blue is the existing transient and orange is the desired one.

[image]

2. It is necessary that the solution of the differential equation be bounded from above and below by an exponential signal, i.e:

[image]

Blue and orange are the upper and lower boundaries. Red - a transient process that does not go beyond their limits and converges to an extremum.

**Problem:**  Build such a control system so that the required *cost function* $J$ so that the transient process from $x(0)$ to $x_*$ in the system is exponential, or make sure that the transient process does not go beyond the required boundaries

We know and are available for measurement: $x$,$x^{'}$,$F$,$\frac{dF}{dx}$.

I am new to optimal control of partial differential equations. I can't seem to figure out how to find an approach to this problem, so any help would be appreciated. I thank all the helpers.

Comment: Your system is given by $\dot{x} = \frac{-2x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}$. It is nonlinear, and the transients are not exponential. To change the behavior of the system, you need something that you can control, e.g., the input control signal.

Comment: Linear systems have an exponential rate of convergance. Set $u = \frac{2x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}-x$. Then $\dot{x}=-x$ and the convergence is exponential.

Comment: You start with one question, and then you switch to another; I can hardly help here. But it seems that you are working with the extremum seeking problem.

Comment: If you know $x$ and $F$ then you can always compute $x_*$, is that right?

Comment: @Arastas
provided that the structure of the function is known to us, I assume that it is unknown

Answer (score 1):

The answer is trivial and I am not sure if it is what you want.

Define $e=x-x_*$, then the dynamics of the error is
$$
\dot{e} = \frac{-2e}{\left(1+e^2\right)^2}.
$$
Note that if $e_0=e(0)$ is bounded then the convergence is exponential, where the rate of the convergence depends on $e_0$.

If you want $e$ to converge to zero exponentially with the rate $\kappa$ then one possible cost function is
$$
J(e) = \int_0^\infty \left(e(\tau)-e_0\exp(-\kappa \tau)\right)^2d\tau.
$$
Another $J$ ensuring the exponential convergence is
$$
J(e,\dot{e}) = \int_0^\infty \left(e(\tau)+\kappa\dot{e}(\tau)\right)^2d\tau.
$$
You see that both $J$ are defined with respect to $e$, i.e., with respect to $x$ and $x_*$.

#### Control

To get the exponential convergence with the constant rate $\kappa$ you choose
$$
u = -\frac{df}{dx} -\kappa e.
$$
Note that to implement is you must know your $x_*$. If it is not the case, then I do not see how to get a constant rate of convergence. However, recall that for any initial condition your system is exponentially converging as it is bounded by
$$
|e(t)| \le e_0 \exp\left(-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+e_0^2}\right)^2t\right).
$$

Comment: @dtn see the updated answer

Comment: Can we get somehow $$
e_1 \exp\left(-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+e_1^2}\right)^2t\right) <
|e(t)| < e_0 \exp\left(-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+e_0^2}\right)^2t\right).
$$, where $e_1<e(0)<e_0$

Comment: @dtn, sure. The lower bond is $e_0\exp(-2t)$.

Comment: @dtn Maybe. You should be more precise on what is the control problem: what is known what is measured, what is controlled, and what is the control goal. Consider asking a new properly formulated question.

Comment: @dtn As I told you, the transients are already exponential with the rate of convergence defined by the initial condition. If you want to specify the rate of convergence, I do not at the moment see how to do it without the knowledge of $x_*$.

Comment: i need to get the result like in the second picture

Comment: Help me deal with this issue 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012542/stabilization-of-the-gradient-equation-in-a-finite-time

Comment: @dtn sorry, I do not know the answer

Comment: And this? : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4015926/which-way-of-solving-from-nonlinear-control-to-choose?noredirect=1#comment8290257_4015926