# Which way of solving from nonlinear control to choose?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics, adaptive-control

I have a nonlinear system:

\begin{cases} x'=f(x)+u \\ y=f(x) \end{cases}

where $f(x)$ - gradient of some one-extremal function (for example $f=e^{-(x)^2}$), i.e. $\frac{df}{dx}$.

**Task:**
I want construct a continuous control $u$ that ensures the following condition:

$y(t)=y(0) e^{-\beta t}, \beta>0$

*Which method to use for the solution: MRAC, asymptotic output tracking, feedback linearization, or something else?*

I am not an expert, please do not pass by and give advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stabilization of the gradient equation in a finite time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012542/stabilization-of-the-gradient-equation-in-a-finite-time)

Comment: @Kwin van der Veen And where is the answer?

Comment: Is there a reason why a very similar question is being asked..3 times in a row? See the two previous questions you've asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4011954/bounded-settling-time-in-nonlinear-ode) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012542/stabilization-of-the-gradient-equation-in-a-finite-time). I don't think asking a very similar question with less detail is going to drive a higher engagement and result in an answer.

Comment: @Rollen I have not provided enough information. What else is needed ?

Comment: I think the assumptions on $f$ are just not strict enough to demand one single method that universally works. You can do input output feedback linearization, for example, under certain additional assumptions on $f.$ You can easily check what those are by just differentiating $y$ with time.